# Who ruled Arrakis before the Harkonnens?

Tags: dune

It's is explained in the first "Dune" book that the Harkonnens have had the stewardship of Arrakis for 80 years before handing it over to the Atreides but who had the 'fief' before them?

Comment: Thief = A naughty person who takes things that aren't theirs. Fief = An estate of land under feudal control

Comment: @Valorum keeping me right again, it been a long day and predictive text not helping me much!

Comment: A race of Arraknids.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you consider the prequel books by Herbert's son to be canon, the answer is that the fiefdom of Arrakis was previously held by House Richese.

> "As our ambassador has explained repeatedly to your emissaries,"
> Calimar added.
>
> "Since my House lost control of the spice operations on Arrakis -- you
> replaced us, don't forget -- we have attempted to rebuild our economic
> foundation." The Premier held his chin high, pretending that he still
> had some pride left.
>
> "Initially, the downfall of Ix was a boon to us, removing competition.
> However, our finances remain somewhat . . . strained."
>
> The Baron's spider-black eyes flashed, relishing Calimar's
> embarrassment. House Richese, manufacturers of exotic weaponry and
> complex machines, experts in miniaturization and Richesian mirrors,
> had made initial market-share gains against rival Ixian companies
> during the upheavals on Ix.
>
> <sub><sup>[House Harkonnen: Prelude to Dune #2](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20253.House_Harkonnen)</sup></sub>

Comment: haven't been through the Herbert Jr stuff yet but is there any reason they are not cannon other than staunch fans not accepting it?

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Well, they're supposedly based on Herbert Sr.'s notes, but in reality I suspect that they're just ghost-written using his family name and a few pages of rough outlines. Also, they're quite badly written.

Comment: Oh well, might save myself the effort and give them a pass. Do you know if there is a definitive canon encyclopaedia? Would be good to be as up to speak as possible for the Villeneuve outing

Comment: The [*Dune Encyclopedia*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dune_Encyclopedia) is worth a read. It's no longer considered canon but it's still excellent. You'd probably also enjoy (and find useful) *[The Road to Dune*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_to_Dune) as it contains some info about how Herbert got from the short story to the full novel and beyond

Comment: The Encyclopedia was never canon, in fact. It's written from an *in-universe* perspective, post-*God Emperor*, and gets lots of things wrong on purpose. (There's a whole article arguing that Paul and Chani were mythological figures who didn't really exist, for example.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Herbert wrote the foreword for the first edition as well as reading each of the articles. He gave it "*[his] delighted approval*" albeit reserving the right to ignore it if he so desired. His son finally (officially) de-canonised it *after* Herbert's death.